# Number of conjugacy classes in a set of subgroups of $S_5$ which are isomorphic to klein's 4 group.

Tags: symmetric-groups, group-isomorphism

Let, *K* be a set of subgroups of *S*<sub>5</sub> (symmetric group of 5 elements) that are isomorphic to the non-cyclic group of order 4. How many conjugacy classes are there in *K*?

I know that a non-cyclic group of order 4 is isomorphic to *K*<sub>4</sub>. Now, do I have to find manually all the subgroups isomorphic to *K*<sub>4</sub> and their conjugate groups? Is there any intuitional shortcut?